# it count it, even if cell is blank

Tags: excel

I’ve put on formula below to leave this cell empty if cell AQ2184 is empty, but still gives me one in some random instances. Other times it leaves it empty. There is a formula In the cells to count which I guess it’s why it counts the cell as if there is character even that it’s empty….what I find very confusing is that it only does it the odd times, but when it does it drives me crazy because I don’t know why it’s behaving like this. If I take the formula off and simply enter the number/s, it works fine, but I need the formula in column AS. I've tried changing the format to number, general and text, but no matter what I do it always does the odd thing in one row or another......why? is there anything I could do?

=IF(ISBLANK(AQ2184),"",COUNT(AS2184))

Also tried; =IF(AS2190>=1,"1","") but it doesn't behave

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF(AQ2184="","",COUNT(AS2184))
```